# MySQL - Restarted laptop and all databases are gone?

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL 5.6 on a Windows 7 Laptop. I restarted my laptop, came back on and for some reason it wasn't started. So I went to command prompt and restarted it (as it's not a service) only to find out my MySQL user got deleted?

Basically it's like my old MySQL user is just gone, 1. All my databases are gone which is weeks of work (as well as my database backups) 2. My root user doesn't have a password anymore?

Anyone know what's going on? Can I get my databases back? It wasn't a version upgrade or a laptop upgrade. I simply restarted my laptop as it was lagging a bit.

Anyone any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: You back up your databases as a running database on the same server?!

Comment: check the c:\programdata\mysql.x.x\data\

Comment: As for the actual problem: Did you change the mysql configuration between the last time you started the service and the next time you started the service? What is in your mysql log?

Comment: Did you [create your tables in memory?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

Comment: Sumurai8 No, they were in my data file for some reason.

@EngineerCoder I don't have a programdata file? I've searched through my MySQL folders no sign of it.

No config to do with MySQL or anything was changed. I simply restarted my laptop as it was getting slow.

Comment: @MichaelWebb i wrote the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Referred to your comments:

Yes you have the folder but it is hidden.
Type `win+R` or click run from start menu. And type : `c:\programdata\` type enter and open `mysql\data` folder.
Probably you will find your data in this path.

**EDIT :**

Copy the Data folder safe place first. And then remove all mysql and all related files. Perform clean install. And replace your existing data folder to new one. That's all.

Comment: Yes! It's there, but now, how do I install it? I tried mysqld --install--default-file"C:\programdata\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" but when I start the service I get a 1067 error saying it can't be found

Comment: Copy the Data folder safe place first. And then remove all mysql and all related files. Perform clean install. And replace your existing data folder to new one. That's all. If works please accept my answer. Regards.